# Функция с переменным количеством аргументов *args

Tags: python, функции, for

Читаю книгу "Укус питона", прохожу тему "Функции", не могу взять в толк, как сработал код, приведенный в примере. Попытался поэтапно просмотреть выполнение этого кода в интерпретаторе - ясности это не добавило.

По моему разумению должно быть так. Я явно что-то не так понимаю, поправьте, пожалуйста. При вызове функции аргументу `extra_numbers` присваивается значение 50, в `*numbers` помещаются значения `(10, 1, 2, 3)`, аргумент `initial = 5` никак не изменяется, затем выполняется тело функции, по моему мнению следующим образом:

1. Переменной `count` присваиваться значение аргумента `initial`, то есть `5`.
2. Далее в цикле `for` идет перебор параметров аргумента `*numbers` измененное значение, телом цикла, которых на каждой итерации цикла хранятся в переменной `number`.
3. На первой итерации цикла `for` берётся первый параметр аргумента `*numbers`, то есть `10`, и складывает со значением переменной `count`. Выходит `15`, изменяя значение переменной `count` собственно на `15`.
4. На второй итерации цикла `for` берется второй параметр аргумета `*numbers`, то есть `1`, и складывается со значением переменной `count`, то есть со значением `15` и переменная получает новое значение `16`, которое и хранит
5. На третье итерации цикла происходит аналогичное тому, что происходило в 1. и 2. примере то есть переменная `count` изменяется значала до `18` и на следующей итерации цикла на `21`
6. Затем цикл `for` прекращает работу и выполняется следующее выражение функции `total`, а именно `count += extra_numbers`, по итогам которого переменной `count` присваивается значение `71`, так как её значение под конец цикла было 18, а значение аргумента `extra_numbers` - `50`.
   А теперь вопрос, откуда взялось 66 и где я протупил?

```
def total(initial = 5, *numbers, extra_numbers):
    count = initial
    for number in numbers:
        count += number
    count += extra_numbers
    print(count)
    
total(10, 1, 2, 3, extra_numbers = 50)

#Вывод в консоль: 66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы немного не так поняли. Аргументу `initial` присваивается значение `10`, потому что он стоит на первом месте. `= 5` - это параметр по умолчанию. Если бы мы написали так:

```
total(numbers = (10, 1, 2, 3), extra_numbers = 50)
```

то было бы так, как вы сказали. А сейчас `initial = 10`, `numbers = (1, 2, 3)`, `extra_numbers = 50`

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь понял, то есть параметры присваиваются с лева на право, первый параметр `10` пристроился к аргументу `initial`, но из за того, что аргумент `*numbers` принимает не ограниченное число параметров, то все оставшиеся параметры не распределились между оставшимися 2 аргументами, а скажем так, провалились все в аргумент `*numbers`

Answer (score 1):

Добавим печать аргументов функции:

```
def total(initial = 5, *numbers, extra_numbers):
    print(initial, numbers, extra_numbers)
    
total(10, 1, 2, 3, extra_numbers = 50)
```

Вывод:

```
10 (1, 2, 3) 50
```

Переданные неименованные аргументы присваиваются последовательно. Поэтому 10 попадает в `initial`, всё кроме `extra_numbers` попадает в `numbers`, а конкретно указанное по имени `extra_numbers` попадает в соответствующую переменную.